# How to count total number of rows in a view which retrieved from database

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter

I want to display some column in a table. Also, want to count the total number of rows showing in the table. I tried some ways, can you please help me if this is the right way or there are other better ways to do this.

my Model

```
public function getRentedEquipments($project_id=0){

     return $this->db->select('e.*, p.project_id')
               ->from('equipment AS e')
               ->join('project AS p', 'p.project_id = e.project_id')
               ->where('p.project_id', $project_id)
               ->order_by('eq_name','ASC' )
               ->get()->result_array();
}
```

My view

```
<tbody>

<?php 

$total_eq=0;
  $count=1;
  foreach ($pr_eq as $row) {
?>

 <tr>
      <th scope="row"><?php echo $count;?></th>
      <th scope="row"><?php echo $row['eq_id'];?> </th>
      <th scope="row"><?php echo $row['eq_name'];?> </th>

  <?php
 $total_eq+=$row['eq_id']-1;
  $count=$count+1;
  }

?>
<button class="btn btn-info"> Number of Equipments: <?php echo $total_eq;?></button> 
  </tbody>
```

The output is showing correctly, but I just want to know if there are any better ways to do this.
[image: My output]

Answer (score 1):

imho there is no need for counting your items in that way - just try this

```
<tbody>
<?php 
foreach ($pr_eq as $row) 
{
?>

 <tr>
      <th scope="row"><?php echo $count;?></th>
      <th scope="row"><?php echo $row['eq_id'];?> </th>
      <th scope="row"><?php echo $row['eq_name'];?> </th>
 </tr>
<?php
}
?>
</tbody>
<button class="btn btn-info"> Number of Equipments: <?= count($pr_eq);?></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

We could take this a step further adding in some checking on the array (which is overkill in this case as ->result_array() used in the model will always return an array ) and using php's if () ; endif; functionality which can be more readable with embedded HTML.

```
<?php
// If we have an array get the count, else its 0
$equipment_count = is_array($pr_eq) ? count($pr_eq) : 0; 

// If we have a count > 0 , it must be an array
if ($equipment_count > 0): ?>
    <tbody>
    <?php foreach ($pr_eq as $row): ?>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row"><?php echo $count; ?></th>
            <th scope="row"><?php echo $row['eq_id']; ?> </th>
            <th scope="row"><?php echo $row['eq_name']; ?> </th>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
<?php endif; ?>
<button class="btn btn-info"> Number of Equipments: <?= $equipment_count; ?></button>
```

Technically you could have an array which has a 0 count, which will fail executing the foreach, which it will do anyway. So that all seems safe.

I have your `<tbody>` tags inside the conditional, so if they need to be outside, you can fix it to suit.

Comment: you maybe right - but in this case there is no need for checking it in that way because Codeigniters `result_array` method returns always an array - if there are no results you get an empty array back